# SQL statement error: I want to select the user that has the most wins

Tags: mysql

There's two table, users and auctions, I'm trying to get the `id`, `firstname` and `lastname` of the user that has the most wins within a specific time, win is verified by a.closed that has the value 1.

```
 SELECT a.winner_id AS 'Winners.id', u.first_name AS 'Winners first name', u.last_name AS 'Winners last name',
                            COUNT( * ) as count
                            FROM    auctions a
                            RIGHT JOIN users u ON a.winner_id = u.id
                            GROUP BY a.winner_id
                            ORDER BY a.winner_id
                            WHERE a.closed = '1' DESC AND
                            BETWEEN '".$dateFrom." 00:00:00' AND '".$dateTo." 23:59:59'
                            LIMIT    1
```

unfortunately I got this error:

```
  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE a.closed = '1' DESC AND BETWEEN '".$dateFrom." 00:00:00' AND '".$' at line 7
```

Comment: I have a suspicion that it's something to do with your SQL syntax. Possibly near `'WHERE a.closed = '1' DESC AND`.

Comment: Check the where clause. Specifically the desc keyword. And the between not having anything to check.

Comment: I suggest you read about basic SELECT syntax here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Comment: Maybe the keyword `DESC` has to be at the end of the request. Like `SELECT * FROM table ... ORDER BY table.a DESC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You syntax is wrong. It must be `select .. from ... join .. where ..group by .. order by ...`

```
SELECT a.winner_id AS 'Winners.id', u.first_name AS 'Winners first name', u.last_name AS 'Winners last name',
COUNT(*) as count
FROM  auctions a
RIGHT JOIN users u ON a.winner_id = u.id
WHERE a.closed = '1' AND
BETWEEN '".$dateFrom." 00:00:00' AND '".$dateTo." 23:59:59'
GROUP BY a.winner_id
ORDER BY a.winner_id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax near the `where` clause is not correct. `DESC` and `ASC` are basically used with the `ORDER BY` clause.

Next the `GROUP BY` clause and `ORDER BY` clause comes after the `where` clause. You need to go through the [MYSQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) to find the syntax in detail.

So you try like

```
SELECT a.winner_id AS 'Winners.id', u.first_name AS 'Winners first name', u.last_name AS 'Winners last name',
 COUNT( * ) as count
 FROM    auctions a
  RIGHT JOIN users u ON a.winner_id = u.id
   WHERE a.closed = '1' AND
   datecolumn BETWEEN  '00:00:00' AND  '23:59:59' --Change it as per your datecolumn name
   GROUP BY a.winner_id
   ORDER BY a.winner_id DESC 
   LIMIT    1
```

Comment: That's not the only problem, OP also placed GROUP BY and ORDER clause in the wrong place ...

Comment: `WHERE a.closed = '1' AND BETWEEN` seems to be missing something ... but that's OP error too.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari:- Yes I tried to add that as well. But not sure with the exact column names so focussed on the syntax part!

Answer (score 0):

you can do order at the end of query and for desc you need to first use order by with some column.

You can try below-

```
SELECT a.winner_id AS 'Winners.id', u.first_name AS 'Winners first name', u.last_name AS 'Winners last name',
                            COUNT( * ) as count
                            FROM    auctions a
                            RIGHT JOIN users u ON a.winner_id = u.id
                            WHERE a.closed = '1' 
                            and BETWEEN '".$dateFrom." 00:00:00' AND '".$dateTo." 23:59:59'
                            group by a.winner_id 
                            order by a.winner_id desc LIMIT    1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE ...` must be before the `GROUP BY ...` in the select statement.

Try changing this.

see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html

If you need selecting and sorting an then selecting from that, you should use a subquery.

see here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/from-clause-subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT Thanks Everyone.
     SELECT a.winner_id AS  'Users Id', u.first_name AS  'First Name', u.last_name AS  'Last Name', COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Auctions Won'
                                FROM auctions a
                                RIGHT JOIN users u ON a.winner_id = u.id
                                WHERE a.closed =  '1' AND a.end_time 
                                BETWEEN '".$dateFrom." 00:00:00' AND '".$dateTo." 23:59:59'
                                GROUP BY a.winner_id
                                ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                                LIMIT 1